# Why hasn't South Korea restored its monarchy?

Tags: monarchy, south-korea

I can understand North Korea not wanting to restore the Korean monarchy to its country, as I assume they are officially opposed to feudalism, but I don't understand South Korea not doing so.

Korea lost its monarchy because of its annexation by Japan, which I suspect is viewed as lacking in legitimacy by South Koreans. I also doubt that South Koreans have a strong ideological opposition to the institution of monarchy, akin to what exists in Australia. I also assume South Korea would like to restore Korea to its former greatness as much as possible.

Why hasn't South Korea re-instated (or instated, if you regard South Korea as separate from the Korean Empire) the monarchy?

Comment: Are you interested in why they haven't adopted a modern-style monarchy (with a figurehead/head of state such as many European countries have), why they haven't adopted a pre-Japan-style monarchy (with king as head of government), or both?

Comment: Considering how much Brits pay for theirs, why would they bother to?

Comment: @Bobson "modern-style" is a bit confusing. I think that even before the American occupation, the Emperor of Japan had minimal practical influence in Japan. I assumed the same would be true for the Korean Empire, but in any case, I'd assume any future monarchy in South Korea would be a constitutional one like the UK or Japan, not an absolute one like Saudi Arabia.

Comment: @user4012 that's like saying you shouldn't cosplay because it's expensive. :) (The only difference being that it's taxpayers' money as opposed to a private individual's money)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - and, as the main reason I personally don't cosplay is indeed the expense, your example has just spectacularly proven my theory right :)))

Comment: @user4012 The British monarchy [is actually a great source of income for the UK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhyYgnhhKFw) (however, a new Korean monarch would not have crown lands to lend to the Korean government and how much tourism income he or she would generate is also debatable, so this doesn't apply).

Comment: @Philipp  - +1 for CGP Grey. -1 for assuming that granting lands to the crown instead of to anyone else is a net income benefit for Britain (IOW, that if the crown lands were nationalized, the income from the new owners and overall economic activity wouldn't surpass status quo)

Comment: @user4012 The crown lands *can not be nationalized* because they are the private property of Elizabeth II. She inherited them from her father who inherited them from his father and so on. But this isn't really important for this question, because it doesn't apply to South Korea. So please let us stay on topic, ok?

Comment: @Philipp - The South Korea is exactly what I meant - the economic difference is between giving X lands to newly instated monarch, vs. not giving them. If you do, you lose economic benefit you gain now. If yuo don't, you don't get the income from the crown equivalent to what Britain is getting.

Comment: A couple of ideas: a long time under Japanese occupation (36 years), even before that the Kings and Emperors appear to have been weak towards the Japanese, the [last emperor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunjong_of_Korea) appears to have had no sons (so stablishing a successor was complicated) and after WWII it was occupied by the USA, which in a *tabula rasa* scenario would be probably more comfortable with a Republic (not to mention that it is easier to depose a President than a King if needed).

Comment: Why hasn't Germany restored its monarchy? Why hasn't Russia? Why do you think Korea would have wanted to restore its monarchy? **I also assume South Korea would like to restore Korea to its former greatness as much as possible.** Your question is flawed and doesn't make sense at all. And how is this question related with Politics? I think your question is better suited on History SE.

Comment: @Ranthony both Germany and Russia lost their monarchies to rebellions largely native to their countries.

Comment: I think this question would be greatly improved with some evidence that there is a desire by the population or some faction of them, to restore the monarchy.

Comment: I think this question would be gretly improved by extending them to all modernized countires who lost their monarchy recently in the course of history, such as Germany, Russia, Romania, Italy, Greece, Turkey, and so on and so forth...

Comment: Don't Australians have a queen ?

Comment: @Evargalo Australia has a queen, and we have the UK pay for her!

Comment: Then why this: " a strong ideological opposition to the institution of monarchy, akin to what exists in Australia." ?

Comment: @Evargalo many Aussies are opposed to the monarchy. Eg https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Republic_Movement

Comment: @Rathony Doesn't seem to be a history question to me. It's a question about a hypothetical future, not about the past.

Answer (score 11):

The last monarch of the short lived Korean Empire (preceded by the Kingdom of Korea) abdicated under occupying Japanese pressure in 1910.

Now, 107 years later, one of the key issues would be how to decide who to make the king of a reinstated constitutional monarchy. Reinstating a descendant of the last monarch of Korea's great, great grandchild or something like that is an idea with not nearly as much appeal as the idea of taking someone who have founded the nation or otherwise earned the respect of the people by leading the country for a long time and formally calling that person the King.

This problem is a general one which causes most Republics to establish the elected office of President to do what a monarch in a constitutional monarchy would do, rather than establishing a monarchy.

North Korea, whose third generation leader Kim Jong Un is a *de facto* absolute monarch, is much more typical of how monarchy has emerged historically. Some powerful figure managed to gain control of the state somehow or other, and has enough control of the state to pass it on to his descendants until this is viewed as legitimate and normal, as opposed to a corrupt circumvention of some other political system or dynasty of monarchs.

A fictional treatment in [graphic nove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goong_(manhwa))l and [television series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Hours) form called Goong imagines what Korea might be like if the monarchy had not been abolished, in a mostly pro-monarchy treatment.

Comment: To add to the issue of the 107-year gap (Now even longer), even if reinstating a descendant of the monarchy to a monarchy would be a thing that South Korea would decide to do, it would be likely fraught with a [succession crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succession_crisis). If they were to go that route, they'd probably wait until North and South Korea were united in the first place before potentially destabilizing it again.

Answer (score 10):

Not only that there is no perceived need by the people of South Korea to restore its monarchy, but also there is really no one that is a good potential monarch out there.

After the Japanese annexation of Korea, the Korean imperial House of Yi became members of the Japanese imperial house (House of Yamato), and the deposed Korean Emperor were accorded the status equivalent to Japanese imperial princes. After World War II, most Japanese imperials lost their status - so did the Korean imperial family.

The last Korean Emperor, Emperor Sunjong, was infertile, so the cognatic line of the House of Yi has died away. There were brothers and nephews of Emperor Sunjong, but there is a problem - many of them have joined the Imperial Japanese Army during wartime (as did most Japanese imperial family members), and this certainly would be more or less unwelcome in Korea. In fact, Yi Un, the Crown Prince Euimin, was not even allowed to return to South Korea (presumably for his association with the Japanese military).

So there definitely wasn't a positive image associated with the House of Yi in Korea - but who else could be a good potential monarch of Korea? The Goreyo kingdom is a distant past, and descendants of the Kingdom of Goreyo's House of Wang are almost impossible to find. In addition, unlike Europe, there wasn't a hereditary nobility in Korea, so there are no high nobles who could become a potential monarch. A new royal house could certainly be proclaimed - but this wouldn't be too legitimate of a new regime.

In conclusion, even if the Koreans wanted their monarchy back, they would have a hard time finding a good candidate for the throne. And Koreans didn't want a monarchy as well (why fixed something that's not wrong) - so almost no one wants the restoration of the Korean monarchy.

Answer (score 4):

The current form of government is a democratic republic. Since "Korea" is not some kind of monolithic, independently sentient being, the question is really, "Why don't **the PEOPLE** of South Korea restore a monarchy?"

Since democratic forms of government have greater control and power residing with the people through the electoral process, this would mean the people ceding power to an autocrat.

While there are many instances of power being moved from autocrats to the people, I can't think there are many, if any, instances of the people willingly choosing to move the other way.

Other than "it once was that way," I really can't see any arguments for why a society would want to do that.

Comment: This is a very old-fashioned view of monarchy. I'd hardly describe Queen Elizabeth of the UK as an autocrat, for example.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Queen Elizabeth is *more autocratic* than (hypothetical) President Elizabeth

Comment: @Caleth "Autocratic" simply isn't a useful word to use. All you're saying is that the word is more applicable to her than to a hypothetical person to whom it would be even less applicable. So what?

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Do you really think OP is asking why South Korea doesn't create a completely powerless and ceremonial figurehead in as a step with the intent to "restore greatness"?  He specifically used the word "restore," - the last Korean monarch was one that wielded autocratic powers.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet When the UK restored its monarchy after the civil war, the new monarch had considerably reduced power. So why not in South Korea?

Comment: @DavidRicherby - They reinstalled the position of monarch, but, by definition, if the powers were greatly reduced, it is not a "restoration" of the monarchy. It is the installation of a very different kind of monarchy.  The key is "restore" and OP is not asking about a just the title, but the monarchy, itself.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Sorry but "restoration" has a wider meaning than you think. The period during which the UK returned to monarchy, and the act of doing so, is always referred to as "[The Restoration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restoration_(England))". It would be a "restoration" if South Korea adopted any kind of monarchy.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - No, it really doesn't. The fact that it was misused as a formal name/title does not change its base definition, and it certainly does not change the very relevant context that OP used here.  If I decided to refer to myself as "the ultimate bad---," but was actually a rather wimpy fellow, the fact that I called myself something would not actually change it's original and common definition. You're really grasping at straws.  OP's intent is very clear.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet No, really. The British Restoration is always called a restoration. The [Bourbon Restoration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbon_Restoration) is always called a restoration, even though France was an absolute monarchy before Napoleon and a constitutional monarchy after. You can shout until you're blue in the face that "restoration" doesn't mean those things but it's quite clear from usage that it _does_. Any "original" definition of the word is irrelevant: we are using the word today and, today, "restoration" does not have the narrow meaning you insist that it does.

Comment: Also, from the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/163986) (subscription required): "_restoration_, n. 1a) The action of restoring a person to a former state or position; the fact of being restored or reinstated; spec. the return of a monarch to a throne, a head of state to government, or a regime to power." No mention of "with exactly the same powers before" and note that since the OED is arranged chronologically, this is what you call its "base definition" and its "original... definition".

Comment: @DavidRicherby - AGAIN, since the "monarchy" being "restored" would be fundamentally different than what was there, before, it would not be a restoration of the monarchy.  If you look at the definition, they are all specific to returning the SAME regime or person to an office they previously held, so even the definitions you cite do not support your scenario. If you had an absolute monarchy, and later have a limited constitutional one, that is FUNDAMENTALLY different, and is a "replacement," not a restoration.

Comment: If a pet dog is lost, and then found, it is restored to its household. If it is never found an another dog is acquired, you wouldn't say that new dog has been "restored" to the family.

Comment: I've pointed out two Restorations that don't meet your definition, I've pointed out a dictionary definition that contradicts you. You, on the other hand, have merely stated your opinion, with which you believe everybody else is out of step. I've shown you the evidence; I can't make you do anything with it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - and, as I've pointed out, an event title has little to no correlation to accurate use of language. That's not even mildly a consideration.  Your only supporting "evidence" are titles of historical events.  That's a lot more subjective than any arguments I've offered. I've also pointed out the clear intent in the context of OP's question.  You have repeatedly ignored that. I like how you somehow claim that "everybody" is on board with your own definition, despite not being able to find a single actual definition that matches your claim.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Also, your claims about the Restoration marking a significantly different monarchy, for England, are not true. Not only was the previous king restored, but with the same powers as before.  Charles even dissolved Parliament and ruled without them for several years. It was not until the Glorious Revolution, in 1688, that Parliamentary supremacy was established.  By the way, that event marks the END of the "Restoration Period," so even your historical examples do not back up your claims.

Comment: I quoted the goddamn dictionary. I’ve cited Wikipedia. I hereby cite every historian who has ever written about the English and/or Bourbon Restoration. You, in contrast, are arguing purely by your own assertion, with literally zero evidence. I will not respond further.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - You misquoted the dictionary, as I pointed out. Actually, if you look at the Wikipedia entry for the English Restoration there is a quote that says "Constitutionally, it was like the previous 19 years never happened," - feel free to actually cite a single historian who mentions any reduced powers for the restored monarchy.  As I noted, that didn't happen until later, and that event marked the END of the "Restoration Period." A simple "before" vs "after" detail would actually support your point, but you can't do that, because your premise is false.